# Time machine over samba, "The identity of the backup disk has changed"

Tags: time-machine, high-sierra, smb

Samba recently added the ability to host time-machine backups over a local network with version 4.8. I set up an old Seagate goflex with Arch linux and followed [this guide](https://www.reddit.com/r/homelab/comments/83vkaz/howto_make_time_machine_backups_on_a_samba/) to get samba running. It's working except that **every time** a backup is started on either of my two laptops I get a warning that "The identity of the backup disk “ArchBackups” has changed since the previous backup." and have to click through. Any idea why my mac isn't trusting the backup server? There is this [old question](https://www.reddit.com/r/homelab/comments/83vkaz/howto_make_time_machine_backups_on_a_samba/) but that seems to be a more intermittent problem on an older version of OSX and never got a satisfactory answer.

Comment: Can you show us how you're mounting the drive... i.e. `/etc/fstab` entry?

Comment: The drive is formatted as LVM and my /etc/fstab is
`/dev/mapper/backupVG-backupLV /backups ext3  defaults  0  2
/dev/mapper/backupVG-swap none  swap  defaults  0  0`

Comment: If I understand this correctly (and I'm pretty sure I don't), you have an ArchLinux host running Samba to share the Seagate (?) drive that you've configured as an LVM... is that correct? If so, perhaps it's the LVM layer that's creating the confusion in that LVM isn't a specific device? But honestly, that's a WAG as I know nothing about LVM - or why it's needed in the role of a TM surrogate.

Comment: The Seagate is a cheap NAS that comes with an embedded linux os. I wiped that and installed Arch instead. I wanted the ability to add more drives in the future so I formatted the single drive as Ext3/LVM.

Comment: OK, so why LVM rather than as a single drive? I don't recall the tutorial you followed specified that. LVM just seems an odd choice to me in this situation.

Comment: Do you think it matters here? For wiping the NAS and installing Arch (with LVM) I followed https://www.cs.cmu.edu/~davide/howto/GoFlexHomeArch.html with the same rationale as the author "I decided to use LVM to make it possible to grow/shrink partitions and to some day make it easier to migrate the data onto a larger disk"

Comment: I am having this problem too, but it isn't on Arch Linux or anything to do with LVM. This is strictly a Time Machine / Samba issue. On the Mac the network share is mounted using the GUI just like you always would. Pretends that everything is fine. Next time a backup is started (even if I force it within a few minutes) always change in identity which causes the backup to be invalidated and the whole machine to be backed-up again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Edit: Find my solution below.**

I have the same problem on Raspian with a Ext4 file system (no LVM). Samba is version 4.8.5, compiled from source by myself. MacOS is High Sierra, backup is encrypted.

Time Machine pretends to have finished the backup successfully. When it starts the next time, the message about the changed identity appears. After choosing "backup anyway", it creates a completely new backup in a new sparse file. (Like @thaimin described it).

On the Samba mailing list someone [states](http://lists-archives.com/samba/115267-4-8-5-timemachine-disk-identity-changed-on-every-connect-cannot-backup-solve.html):

> Recompile samba with  `--enable-spotlight` and all works.

That is not true in my case, because I *did* compile Samba 4.8.5 with this option (what I didn't do is setting up tracker as suggested in this [blog post](https://kirb.me/2018/03/24/using-samba-as-a-time-machine-network-server.html)).

**Workaround**

I compiled Samba in the previous version (4.8.4). Now it works as expected (same system, same dependencies, same configuration).
Someone already created a [bug ticket](https://bugzilla.samba.org/show_bug.cgi?id=13638) for Samba.

Comment: Yes, it seems to have been a bug with samba 4.8.5. I just upgraded to 4.9.2 and the problem has resolved itself.